# Remove leading blank page in Apex PDF page

Tags: pdf, html, visualforce

I am getting a leading blank page in below PDF. Can someone let me know how to remove that?

**Apex page**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" doctype="html-4.01-strict" controller="cntl_FormTemplatePrinter" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false" >

<!--<html>
    <head>

        <style TYPE="text/css" media="print,screen">
            body {font-family: Times-Roman; font-size: 12pt;}
        </style>
    </head>
</html>-->    

<apex:repeat value="{!lstInteger}" var="int"> 

<apex:repeat value="{!formTransactions}" var="sof">
   <div style="page-break-before:avoid;">
    <apex:dynamicComponent id="dcx" componentValue="{!ValidTemplate}" />
        <!--div style="page-break-after:always;">
            <apex:dynamicComponent id="dcx" componentValue="{!ValidTemplate}" />
        </div>-->
  </div>

</apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your CSS : Find the right place where you are creating data of your PDF

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```